# Set formula in a range regarding double quote (" ")

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to use the `Range().Formula` in my codes and I'm having a problem with it since it returns as `FALSE` in the cell.

Here's my code:

`Range("D24").Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP(Q23,STUDENTS_INFO!$C:$R,6,0)="","",VLOOKUP(Q23,STUDENTS_INFO!$C:$R,6,0))"`

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You need to double up the quotes inside the formula.

Comment: Also the check is redundant: `=VLOOKUP(Q23,STUDENTS_INFO!$C:$R,6,0)`. Though I assume you actually mean to use `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Q23,STUDENTS_INFO!$C:$R,6,0),"")`.